# iOS - Auto resize cell height & label height

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new to iOS programming and I am developing an app which has a table view.

The table data is being loaded by a plist file. One row of the table will be long and not consistant, therefore I need dynamic heights.

This is what I have so far:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *cellText    = @"This is a very long peice of text to show up here and here";// this will eventually be data from a plist
    UIFont *cellFont      = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-neuve" size:21.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize      = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    int buffer  = 70;
    return labelSize.height + buffer+100;


   //return 65; 

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";
    static NSString *CellNib = @"DetailViewCell";



    DetailViewCell *cell = (DetailViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (DetailViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];


        cell.cellSubtitleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.cellSubtitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        cell.cellSubtitleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-neuve" size:21.0];




    }   

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


    informations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Title", @"Country", @"State", @"Population",  @"Info",  nil];
    subtitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:titleString, subtitleString, stateString, populationString, @"This is a very long peice of text to show up here and here", nil];


    cell.cellTitleLabel.text = [informations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.cellSubtitleLabel.text = [subtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return (DetailViewCell *) cell; 
}
```

I have managed to get this to a point where the height is ok. But the label text isn't showing. I have narrowed this down the the height of the label. It's at 23 (set in Interface Builder). If I increase the size, it messes up the other cells. I need to change the height of the label based on it's content.

Could someone please help me with this, as I have spend two days of trial and error, and still haven't managed to do it. Also I'm a noob at this, so explain in detail ;)

Many thanks

Ryan.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing the same thing. This is what I do.

Resize the UILabel in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` callback by using the `sizeToFit` method:

```
[contentViewCell.myTextLabel sizeToFit];
```

Hope this will help you.